# questoes sobre categoria e subcategoria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

boa tarde eu  criei um sistema de categoria de produtos na loja que estou montando nela tenho uma pagina que chama por get as categorias mas eu tenho um problema eu tenho mais de uma categoria por produto e nao estou conseguindo fazer lista-lo tanto em uma categoria quanto na outra. se algume puder ajudar agradeco deixarei a parte do index que chama o get da pagina categoria e a pagina da categoria obs: no meu banco de dados eu criei um campo na tabela chamado categoria e um outro chamado subcategoria.

parte do index que chama o get da pagina categoria:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="category.php?category=esportes"><img src="images/prod1.jpg" alt="esportes" class="acende" title="esportes"></a>
                    <span class="esporte">Esportes</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="category.php?category=running"><img src="images/run_prod.jpg" class="acende" title="running"></a>
                    <span class="resto">Running</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

nesse exemplo eu tenho uma listagem de categoria por esportes e running suponha-se que eu tenha um produto que sao dessas duas categorias eu cadastrei na categoria running e na subcategoria esporte como eu poderia fazer para ele listar o msm produto nas duas categorias se eu estiver fazendo errado por favor me expliquem de um modo simples e eficaz ou se nao for desse jeito agradeco qualquer informacao.

agora a pagina de categoria

```
<?php

    $categoria = $_GET['category'];
                $quantidade = 24;// qunatidade que ira aoparecer por pagina
                $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
                $inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria = '$categoria' ORDER BY nome LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
    ?>
```

aqui estao meus codigos se alguem puder ajudar agradeco mesmo.

Comment: O certo é você passar na URL o ID da categoria e não nome, por conta dos caracteres especiais que podem ter. category.php?idCategory=56

Comment: intao no caso eu teria que tirar o where categoria e passar como where id = '$categoria' se for esse o caso como eu iria mostrar no index intao na chamada da url? como eu iria chamar o id nela?

Comment: Você pode listar todas as categorias e o link dela você faz: pagina.php?idCategoria=<? echo $row['idCategoria']; ?>, com isso você consegue buscar os dados que estão dentro dessa categoria, seja produto, texto ou qualquer tipo.

Comment: `suponha-se que eu tenha um produto que sao dessas duas categorias`. Talvez o mais correto seja guardares as categorias num campo `VARCHAR` separado por vírgulas, e quando fores filtrar as categorias, faças um `explode` para processar todas as categorias listadas, embora isso seja algo trabalhoso para o banco de dados. Mas armazenar `ID` para diferentes categorias seria complicado e ainda mais trabalhoso, e talvez tivesses que recorrer à mesma técnica só que desta vez usando `inteiros`, o mais correto seria imaginas isto como `tags`. Será algo assim ?

Comment: bom dia intao cara eu tentei fazer isto usar explode mas deu um problema primeiro vo mostrar o código que fiz agora nele tem um simples erro: $sql = "SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria IS NOT NULL AND categoria LIKE '%$categoria%' ORDER BY nome LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade"; nele seu eu tiver uma categoria com nomes parecidos ele lista ela nas duas sem eu mandar listar mesmo eu dando uma categoria somente para cada ai tentei usar o explode ate consegui mas tive uma problema também ele pegava o atributo depois da virgula ou seja a primeira categoria não pegava, esse e meu erro se puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como você fez para ligar os produtos às categorias, mas uma vez que cada produto pode ter várias categorias, o recomendável é criar uma tabela auxiliar só para fazer essa ligação.
Ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
prod_categoria
================================
produto        | categoria
id do produto  | id da categoria
```

Neste caso, para chamar os produtos pertencentes à categoria desejada, poderia fazer assim:

```
select 
    p.* 
from categoria c
left join prod_categoria pc on c.id = pc.categoria
inner join produto p on p.id = pc.produto
where 
    c.descricao = 'descricao_da_categoria'
```